# Discuss the $k$-differentiability of $f(x, y)=\int_0^{x+y} t^2 \sin(\frac{1}{t})\, dt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to discuss $\forall k$ the $k$-differentiability of the function $f(x,y) = \int_0^{x+y} t^2 \sin(\frac{1}{t}) \, dt$ for any point of its domain.
The first thing I would do is to get the derivatives $f_x(x, y)$ and $f_y(x, y)$ to see where the $f$ is surely $1$-differentiable.

If I try to calculate the partial derivatives normally I have this problem: $f_x(x, y) = (x + y)^2 \sin(\frac 1 {x+y}) - 0^2 \sin(\frac{1}{0})$, what does it mean?

If I try to calculate the generic directional derivative $D_{\underline{v}} f(x,y)$ I get a limit I can't manage.

Which is the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a problem with the $0^2\sin \frac 10$ term?

Consider $\lim_\limits{a\to 0} \int_a^{x} t^2 \sin \frac 1t \ dt$

$\lim_\limits{a\to 0} x^2 \sin \frac 1x + a^2 \sin \frac {1}{a}\\
x^2 \sin \frac 1x + \lim_\limits{a\to 0} a^2 \sin \frac {1}{a}$

This limit does exist, and you can use that.

Eventually though, as you take more derivatives this function will fail to be differentiable at $(0,0).$